# "git log" command output is not clear after conducting a successful simple merge

Tags: git

I have two branches named: "master" and "shorten_title".

I would like to merge "shorten_title" into "master"

latest commits in "master" branch before merge:

[image]

latest commits in "shorten_title" branch before merge:

[image]

Now assume I merged "shorten_title" into master branch using a Real Merge (i.e which requires a merge commit and not via a fast forward merge).

Then, git log on "master" branch post merge shows the following:

[image]

My question is, why git log on master branch post merge shows:

```
b19
834
c091faf
```

instead of:

```
b19
834
dc9c83c
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That just appears to be one of the commits brought in from the other branch. Run `git log --graph --decorate --oneline` to see how the two branches brought together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As best as I understand it, your repo looks something like this:

```
(master)  380f82b --- dc9c83c --- 834641f ------------ b19d932
                          \                             /
                           \                           /
(explore_california)        ----- 6a2a3f5 --- c091faf -
```

your `b19d932` commit (the merge commit) has two parents - one from `master`, and one from the `explore_california` branch.

Running `git log --graph --oneline --all` should give you a better sense of how git is ordering the commits when you just do a plain `git log --oneline`

Comment: Also, `git log` displays the commits in chronological order, so two adjacent commits in the output are not necessarily from the same branch.

Comment: Yup - this is also good example of why squash commits are so useful.  If you squash your merge down into a single commit then your history remains more linear, and it's easier to find out when bugs were introduced using `git bisect`.

Comment: Matt, thanks for the great answer. Can you send a link which explains on "squash commits"? I have never heard on this term.

Comment: You can still use `git bisect` with non-linear history; the process is just easier to understand with linear history. See https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bisect-lk2009.html for information on how the bisection algorithm works in general.

Comment: @Qwerty - this is a nice explanation along with some reasoning why squashing can be preferred: http://jamescooke.info/git-to-squash-or-not-to-squash.html .  In general, I will usually squash all of the commits for a single feature down into a single commit by doing a `git merge --squash my-feature-branch` - just be sure to keep detailed error messages.  Incidentally, this also helps with reverting as well - if you want to rollback a feature, just revert the single commit.